# Accessing data with joined table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I access this table with activerecord?

https://gyazo.com/1f37f5031c37967459c9bb18052886e9

Normally I just do `Singularnameoftable.find(id).whateveriwant`.
But for some reason this is not working.

```
 <% @organisation_ids.each do |x| %>   
   <% @organisationjuridicalform << Organisation.find(x.to_i).juridicalform_id %>
  <% end %>


   <% @organisationjuridicalform.each do |y| %>
     <% @aorgtype << Organisations_organisationtype.find(y.to_i) %>
   <% end %>
```

This gives me following error :

> uninitialized constant
>   ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::Organisations_organisationtype

I tried accessing the table using:

```
Organisation_organisationtype.find

Organisations_organisationtype.find

Organisation_organisationtypes.find

Organisations_organisationtypes.find
```

But all of them give the same  error as if it doesn't know which table I mean.

Is there a special sytax for tables like this? I cannot seem to find anything about it when browsing online.

I need to acces this table in order to find the actual type in this table:
https://gyazo.com/1db9782b1f73e56a50ec660a3c83944c

Comment: you should be able to do something like `OrganisationsOrganisationtype.find(1)`

Comment: This still gives me : (uninitialized constant ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::OrganisationOrganisationtype)

Comment: do you have a model in **app/models/**  can you post the first line of it that calls ActiveRecord *class xxxx < ActiveRecord::Base*

Comment: Depends. You should have a class with that name defined somewhere in `app/models`. If you don't (and that **is** possible) then this table is not meant for direct access (which can be if it's part of HABTM relation). In that case, you should take some time to convert `has_and_belongs_to_many ...` to `has_many ..., through: ...`.

Comment: I guess I don't, I was just hired to make a page that does an excel export from their database in an old rails project.

These are all the models:
https://i.gyazo.com/dcdb2130fb2d53b89e0dd23d89d962c3.png

The Organisationtype looks like this:
class Organisationtype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organisations
end

Comment: See the first comment ! The name should be `OrganisationsOrganisationtype`, but not `OrganisationOrganisationtype` (without 's') as you can see in the error log from the second comment.

Comment: Still the same thing, uninitialized constant ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::OrganisationsOrganisationtype.
I guess its what D-side sais, thing is I can't touch the models itself. Ill figure a way, thanks for your feedback.